# Rename Multi - Index Column name Python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a MultiIndex Dataframe df like Below

```
                 Office
 Office    
 x         True   2
 y         False  3
 z         True   5
```

If i reset  df.reset_index() it will Error as

```
"cannot insert Office, already exists"
```

How its posible to rename the the higher(which comes in very first line) index name "Office" to "Office1"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html) or set `index.names` for rename index names in `MultiIndex` and `rename` for change column name:

```
#if only rename get Unnamed column
df1 = df.rename(columns={'Office':'another col'}).reset_index()
print (df1)
  Office  Unnamed: 1  another col
0      x        True            2
1      y       False            3
2      z        True            5
```

---

```
df2 = df.rename_axis(('Office', 'bool')).rename(columns={'Office':'Office2'}).reset_index()
print (df2)
  Office   bool  Office2
0      x   True        2
1      y  False        3
2      z   True        5

df.index.names = ('Office1','bool')
df3 = df.rename(columns={'Office':'Office2'}).reset_index()
print (df3)
  Office1   bool  Office2
0       x   True        2
1       y  False        3
2       z   True        5
```

Comment: reset_index() got an unexpected keyword argument 'name'

Comment: Sorry, I miss MultiIndex first.

Comment: How to change the Name of column name office having values 2,3,5 to office1 not the other one

Comment: Do you think rename? I add it to answer.