# Changing the column index name in pandas

Tags: pandas

I want to change the column index name

here the column index name (To be more preceise, sequence name) is 'Data Field':-

[image]

To a new sequence name, may be Column1, but when I'm doing

```
df.index.name = 'Column1'
```

It's adding Column1 at the bottom of the previous column index name. Which I don't want

[image]

Comment: This will do: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41221249/6660373

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Rename specific column(s) in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19758364/rename-specific-columns-in-pandas)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46357585/6660373

Comment: @Pygirl thanx, but tried with df.columns = df.columns.rename("Column1", level=1), it's throwing an exception  TypeError: rename() got an unexpected keyword argument 'level'

Comment: can you please give the results of `print (df.columns)`

Comment: in df.columns, 'Data Field' doesn't come, it's actually the column index of the sequence, we can say

Answer (score 0):

You can give `df.rename(columns={})` to replace a specific column name.

```
df.rename(columns={'old column name':'new column name'}, inplace=True)
```

In your specific case, looks like you want to rename `Data Field`. You can give:

```
df.rename(columns={'Data Field': 'Column1'},inplace=True)
```

Comment: Actually, it's not making any change, while giving df.rename(columns={'Data Field':'Column1'}, inplace=True)

Comment: It's more like changing the name of the sequence, thus, whenever I'm accessing and modifying it as a column name, it's not changing anything

Comment: can you please share what df.columns shows?

Answer (score 0):

```
df.rename(columns={'Data Field': 'Column1'},inplace=True)
```

Comment: It's not the name of the column, we cannot access it with df.columns, it's more like the sequence name, which appears on the left most side of the columns

Answer (score 0):

```py
df.columns = df.columns.rename("Column1", level=0)
```

Comment: It's actually adds 'Column1' under the column index I want to change 'Data Field', not removing it.

Comment: I updated my answer following your comment.